# Java callable and prepared statements to the same batch

Tags: java, jdbc

If we have a set of prepared statements and callable statements Is it possible to add callable and prepared statements to the same batch and execute them.

Comment: can you please provide an example so we can help you?

Comment: As callable statement extends prepared statements and i have set of prepared statements and I have callable statement so if I batch both of them would it result in any issue.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because you prepare a single callable (or normal statement), and prepare a batch of value sets for the parameters of that statement for execution. This means that your batch can only consist of a single statement.

The only exception is batching on a `java.sql.Statement`, where you can batch multiple different DML (non-select) statements.